# The method getChildFragmentManager() is undefined

Tags: android, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I have a SherlockFragmentActivity, this Activity have a SectionsPagerAdapter and a ViewPager. When I call the constructor of  the SectionsPagerAdapter with  `getChildFragmentManager()` method, it shows me this error message:

> The method getChildFragmentManager() is undefined for the type ViewPagerActivity

This is my code:

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnPageChangeListener, OnQueryTextListener{

private SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_view_pager);

    sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), this);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    this.getMovements();

    this.getPrizes();

    this.getVouchers();

    this.createDropdownlist(); 
}
```

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and I updated the android-support-v4.jar using *"Android Tools - Add Support Library"* in my project, also on ActionBarSherlock project.

I'm doing this because I need to have a ListFragment inside a Fragment that I use like a page on my ViewPager.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`getChildFragmentManager()` is a method on `Fragment`, not on `FragmentActivity`. Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` on a `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: oh, what A mistake I made. Sorry for that. 

I have a problem using Fragment inside fragment, I'm trying a lot of things (this was one of this) and I didn't see that.

Again, sorry for my mistake